# The required column was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation. ( Stored procedure with Oracle)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

wanted to call a stored procedure with oracle so after searching I found that 
to do this I have to create a model and make context and of these things. but after doing that I got this out of nowhere

> The required column was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

I'm working with asp core 2.2 and EF Core 2.2.1, now I'm getting these and I can't figure it out how to fix it or what is wrong .

I tried many things but nothing changes

Here are my files

Model

```
namespace test2._2.Models
{
    public class CodeProc
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Erorrcode { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Context

```
namespace test2._2.Models
{
    public partial class ModelCodingContext : DbContext
    {
        public ModelCodingContext(DbContextOptions<ModelCodingContext> optionss)
            : base(optionss)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<CodeProc> CodeProcs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the actual procedure to call and run and print the results

```
var result = await _dbCodingContext.CodeProcs.FromSql("begin FIX_CODING.GET_CLIENT_CODE12(245,255,:num1,:num2,:msg);end;", oracleParameter, oracleParameter2, oracleParameter3).ToArrayAsync();

ViewData["test"] += result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, I solved my own by making the stored procedure to return a refcursor rather than 3 values and it went for good. but I wonder what to do if it returns values not a refcursor.

Answer (score 0):

Your required columns are: `ID`, `Erorrcode`, `ErrorMsg`

Check that the stored procedures returns exactly these columns. Account for case sensitivity, so `'ID'` doesn't equal `'Id'` as well as `'Errorcode'` doesn't equal `'ErrorCode'`.

Comment: Thanks for saying this you saved me from struggling with different columns names in the future but for this one it wasn't my case, I solved my own by making the stored procedure to return a refcursor rather than 3 values and it went for good. but I wonder what to do if it returns values not a recursor.